# RegEx anomalous behavior in a program

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following regex to match a set of e-mails from HTML files. The e-mails can take various formats such as

```
alice @ so.edu
alice at sm.so.edu
alice @ sm.com
<a href="mailto:alice at bob dot com">
```

I generally use [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) to test my regular expressions before implementing them in a programing language. I observe a strange behavior on the last e-mail example posted. RegexPal shows me a match for my regex but while using the same regex in a Python program it doesn't give me a hit. What could be the reason?

```
 mail_regex = (?:[a-zA-Z]+[\w+\.]+[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:@|\bat\b)\s*(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\s*
(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*)(?:edu|com))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s*(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*(?:edu|com))))
```

The RegEx is a little bit complex to accommodate variety of other examples (email patterns found in the dataset). You can also run and inspect the Python program on CodePad - http://codepad.org/W2p6waBb

**Edit**

Just to give a perspective the same regex works on - http://pythonregex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the specific issue here is that you need to use a raw string:

```
mail_re = r"(?:[a-zA-Z]+[\w+\.]+[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:@|\bat\b)\s*(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*(?:[a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*)(?:edu|com))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s*(?:\.|dot|dom)\s*(?:edu|com))))"
```

Otherwise, for instance `\b` will be backspace instead of word boundary.

Also, you're using a JavaScript tester.  Python has different syntax and behavior.  To avoid surprises, it would better to test with the Python-specific syntax.

Comment: And what would that be, if I may ask ? I can confirm that the pattern doesn't match in Python. I find that a bit surprising unless the RegEx language I write is different.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that out. 10 hours of my hard work down the drain. Will never forget this. :-(

Comment: Can you please also elaborate on what you meant by "Python-specific" syntax? Everything in my mentioned regex apart from the prefix r (raw string) was good I guess.

Comment: @mcenley, I never said *your* regex was different (I hadn't analyzed it yet).  But it could have been the issue, and it remains a good best practice.  See [this comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

Comment: Thanks.I will shift to an online python regex evaluator. My regex is too complex and hence can't be modified on the terminal.